# How to keep overview of the migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a question regarding my migrations in rails.
Normally when i want to add a colum to a model for i dont make extra migrations but instead i perform this steps:

```
  rake db:rollback
```

next i change the migration file in db/migrations and rerune:

```
  rake db:migrate
```

The biggest problem is that when i do this i loose my data.
Previous i wrote migrations from the command line with for example

```
  rake g migration Add_Column_House_to_Users house:string
```

The problem with this approach is that my db/migrations folder afterwards get very large and not very clear! I mean at the end i dont know wich variables the object has! Im not an expert in rails and would like to ask you how to keep the overview over the migrations!Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't use `db:rollback` with a table with existing data.

I have a few production RonR apps with a ton of data and there are 100+ entries in the migrations table and adding new migrations to tweak tables is the *rails way* to do things. Not sure what you mean by lucid, but your schema and data model are going to change over time and that is ok and expected.

One tip. The migrations are great, but they are just the beginning, you can include complex logic as needed to fix your existing data (like so)

#### Changing data in existing table:

```
def up
    add_column :rsvps, :column_name_id, :integer
    update_data
end

def update_data
    rsvps = Rsvp.where("other_column is not null")
    rsvps.each do |rsvp|
        invite = Blah.find(rsvp.example_id)
        ...
        rsvp.save
    end
end
```

**Another tip**: backup your production database often (should do this anyway), but use it to test all of your migrations before deploying. I run scripts like this all the time for local testing:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword
drop database mydatabase_dev;
create database mydatabase_dev;
use mydatabase_dev;
source /var/www/bak/mydatabase_backup_2013-10-04-16.28.06.sql
exit

rake db:migrate
```

Comment: With lucid i meant clearly, i mean when i have thousands of migrations, at the end i dont know wich variables the object has!

Comment: but i really have to say you thank you from germany! You helped me a lot!

Comment: Lucid is the right word in this context, I'm on the same project most days, so it's probably easier to keep track for me. You could auto-generate a ERD for your app after major migrations. MySQLWorkbench is good for this in mysql. Think Postgres' app has one as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor thought - I just use the file db/migrate/schema.rb to determine whats in the database as opposed to tracking through the migrations

Comment: Thanks i didnt kow that file

Comment: John - thanks for voting uo my answer - I now have enough stackoverflow points points to vote up answers etc. e.g. now have more than 15 points - Pierre